# ng serve won't compile

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to get my very first angular app compiled, but ng serve spits this error:

> ERROR in ./src/styles.scss
>   (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/ang
>   ular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embe
>   dded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
>   Error: Failed to find
>   'angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'   in [
>       C:\Users\juio\Desktop\MY GITHUB\conFusion\src   ]
>       at resolveModule.catch.catch (C:\Users\juio\Desktop\MY GITHUB\conFusion\node
>   _modules\postcss-import\lib\resolve-id.js:35:13)
>       at

I've tried some of the possible answers I've seen on internet but haven't had luck.

```
@import "~angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This is what is causing the problem. If I empty the styles.scss file it compiles but if I write code It won't. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having it on your **Desktop**, move it to **D:\somefolder**, had the same issue and this worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the import path

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

Comment: I solved the problem, as deleted the styles.scss and replaced it with styles.css : )

Comment: Rather changing the extension of 'styles' file you can rebuild sass modules by using:-  npm rebuild node-sass