# How to setup tailwind with Angular custom web component

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

My objective is to setup Tailwind CSS with an Angular custom web component project. Because of the custom web component, I'm using `ngx-build-plus:browser` to serve and build (because this can help bundle everything into a single bundle).

I have then followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@bajzat.tamas/setup-tailwind-css-in-angular-8-project-6e9264e97329) for implementing Tailwind, but when I try to serve the application I get the following error:

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from <path-to-project>/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find '~projects/<web-component-project>/src/styles.scss'
  in [
    <path-to-project>/projects/<web-component-project>/src/app
  ]
    at <path-to-project>/node_modules/postcss-import/lib/resolve-id.js:35:13
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                    ident: 'postcss',
                    syntax: 'postcss-scss',
                    plugins: () => [
                        require('postcss-import'),
                        require('tailwindcss'),
                        require('autoprefixer'),
                    ],
                },
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

**serve-command**

```
ng s --project <project-name> --single-bundle --extra-webpack-config webpack.config.js
```

**tsconfig.base.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "importHelpers": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "lib": ["es2019", "dom", "esnext.asynciterable"],
        "types": ["node", "jest"]
    },
    "exclude": ["cypress", "aveiro-server", "eddyhelp"]
}
```

**projects//tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
        "module": "es2015",
        "target": "es2015",
        "types": []
    },
    "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

What is going on - why is the `postcss-loader` trying to look inside `app` directory - and not `<path-to-project>/projects/<web-component-project>/src/app` where my `styles.scss` lives?

Comment: How did you defined `~projects` path in tsconfig? can you post it please?

Comment: Can you post the complete error please?

Comment: the the `<web-component-project>/tsconfig.app.json` there is no `~projects` path. This file extends the `../../tsconfig.base.json` and here this file contains no `path` property. (will just include the tsconfig file in the question)

Comment: Can you try adding this please: `"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "~projects/*": [ "relative/path/to/projects/folder/*" ]
     }
}`  For example: `"~projects/*": [ "./projects/*" ]`

Comment: Hi @RazRonen - I tried adding this `paths` property to my tsconfig.json file in the root, but did not help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After *a lot* of digging, I have found the solution to the challenge. It was a 2 part issue:

**Inavlid scss imports**

First off, the error message `Error: Failed to find...` originated because the Angular project had multiple component `.scss` files importing like this: `@import '~projects/eddy-library/src/styles.scss';`, and was not related directly to using tailwind at all. My solution to this issue was to remove the imports.

**Issues with Tailwind and shadow DOM**

Second, and maybe more important, was the fact that my web component was using shadow dom, and therefore following the guides of setting up Tailwind did not work. Something I found a discussion about [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/1935#discussioncomment-51445). The only solution seems to be abandoning the shadow DOM, something actually ok in my specific use-case, but I wonder what other web components will do in this case.

I hope this answer can help other people with the same troubles. Big thanks to everyone who tried to help out.

Comment: Not sure how sure how big of an issue the style duplication is, first of all the browser will [not process duplicate styles but read these from the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53270412/308645) so the performance hit is probably minimal, and second of all Webpack will roll up style imports (at least when using Angular) in a separate chunk and fetch that whenever a component requests it so the payload will not be in any way affected when using the Shadow DOM view encapsulation.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to regenerate this issue but did not get any success. My project runs without any error. here is the repo of the project [tailwindcss-in-angular](https://github.com/HirenParekh/tailwindcss-in-angular). I followed the following steps.

1. create a new angular project.

   ```
   ng new tailwindcss-in-angular --create-application=false
   ```
2. generate new application in the project.

   ```
   ng generate application web-component-project
   ```
3. add ngx-build-plus library to the project. (we need to add it to the newly generated application using the `--project` option)

   ```
   ng add ngx-build-plus --project getting-started
   ```
4. create a webpack.partial.js file at the root of your project (i.e. where you have your angular.json file is)

   ```
    const webpack = require('webpack');

    module.exports = {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
           test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'postcss',
              syntax: 'postcss-scss',
              plugins: () => [
                require('postcss-import'),
                require('tailwindcss'),
                require('autoprefixer'),
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    }
   ```
5. install the dependecy packages.

   ```
    npm i autoprefixer postcss-import postcss-loader postcss-scss tailwindcss
   ```
6. generate tailwind.config.js file.

   ```
    npx tailwindcss init
   ```
7. import tailwind in your styles.scss file.

   ```
    /* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
    @import "tailwindcss/base";

    @import "tailwindcss/components";

    @import "tailwindcss/utilities";
   ```
8. remove everything from app.component.html and update it with the following markup.

   ```
    <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
      Button
    </button>
   ```
9. run the project.

   ```
    ng serve --project web-component-project -o --extra-webpack-config webpack.partial.js
   ```

So, why are you getting the error? I googled your error and found these interesting links you can check **Or you can use my boilerplat project directly**

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12981

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/1066

this link says your project might be in the C drive you can move it in some other drive. [ng serve won't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076149/ng-serve-wont-compile)

I don't know what's going in your project and what is causing the error but I am pretty sure it has nothing to do with tailwindcss its the postcss-import which is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt to recreate the issue! I will go through all the settings, and see if I missed something. And I think you are right that it's more of a postcss issue, than tailwind.

Comment: Just tried following the steps one by one, and I get the same error 

Comment: @DauleDK you can try cloning my repo and run it.

Comment: Cloning the project and running it works perfectly. I'm walking through every detail, to try hunt down what is causing the issue.

Comment: @DauleDK here is another blog [Angular and TailwindCSS](https://medium.com/@jacobneterer/angular-and-tailwindcss-2388fb6e0bab)

You can try [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) instad of ngx-build-plus:browser

Comment: Hi, since I'm using this new webpack configuration, I'm having a issue on how to make my `shared/` folder as root. Do you have any Idea where should I look at? I think I should make some update on this webpack config, but I can't find what should I change. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a path issue. Instead of passing the extra-webpack-config in `--extra-webpack-config webpack.config.js`, can you place it in the `angular.json` file?

```
{
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
      "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
           "path": "webpack-dev.config.js"
        }
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

This schematic was released yesterday, and encapsulates a lot of the ideas and techniques for integrating TailwindCSS with Angular:

https://github.com/nartc/tailwindcss-schematics#readme

Comment: I am using ngx-build-plus, because I'm creating a web component.

Comment: Adding the customWebpackConfig here does not seem to work either.